# take place in + time

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, time, range-inclusion

> The motion of the cylinder is to take place **in** 3 seconds.

Does that mean

1. the motion starts **after** 3 seconds
2. the **duration** of the motion of the cylinder is 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Most likely 1, but you can't rule out 2. I would expect "over" instead of "in" if it was 2, but it's not incorrect to mean 2 with "in".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, though, *in* and *after* can function as synonyms. That is,

- *In 3 seconds, it will start to move*

can mean about the same thing as:

- *After 3 seconds, it will start to move*

so long as "immediately" is implied in the latter statement.

---

The reason your statement can be ambiguous is two-fold: first, the way most prepositions are used can vary according to context; second, the acceptable range of "in" and "after" can share an endpoint.

Let's start with *in*; this can mean:

> 1) within (after no more than)
>   2) after exactly
>   3) in approximately

Here are three examples that show those three corresponding usages:

#### 1) **We don't want to be late for the show! We need to leave in ten minutes!**

<sup>(In other words, we don't want to leave any more than ten minutes from now. We could leave in five minutes, though.)</sup>

#### 2) **The rocket will launch in nine seconds.**

<sup>(Rocket launches are very precise – and this is true in many other engineering realms as well.)</sup>

#### 3) **Our baby is due in four weeks.**

<sup>(Everyone knows that a due date is an approximation. Scheduling large projects can also be an inexact science.)</sup>

Similarly, *after* can mean:

> 1) Immediately after a specified time
>   2) Any time after a specified time

For example:

#### 1) **37.3 seconds after the rocket lifts off the ground, the boosters will fire.**

<sup>(Once again, when an engineer says "after," the word "immediately" is often implied.)</sup>

#### 2) **Don't rush into marriage; don't propose until two years after you start dating.**

<sup>(This marital advice doesn't mean you should propose on your 2-year anniversary; it means wait at least two years.)</sup>

---

In short, qualifies such as *exactly, immediately, at least,* and *not more than* are often implied rather than explicitly stated. In day-to-day conversation, this can sometimes lead to erroneous assumptions and misunderstandings – some of which can be amusing. In systems design, though, these assumptions and ambiguities and be a nightmare for program managers, because these quaint misunderstandings can lead to costly mistakes.

Back to your original statement:

> The motion of the cylinder is to take place in 3 seconds.

If that is part of a requirements specification, it probably needs to be reworded. It's unclear, and you don't want half of the design team thinking it means "in exactly 3 seconds" whlie the other engineers assume it means "within 3 seconds."

Answer (score 0):

*take place* means [to occur or happen.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/place) In this context, *'**is to** take place'* means something is *going to happen*.

It is then followed by some specific time i.e. 3 seconds.

To me,

> *In 3 seconds, the cylinder will start moving*

I'd certainly not take it as **'after 3 seconds'**. It uses 'in 3 seconds' means within or in the scope of 3 seconds.

If I want to say the 'duration' of the motion, I'd probably write ..

> The motion of the cylinder *takes place **for** 3 seconds*